# Simple Slot Machine (Classes)

Tags: java, class, random

I finally finished my simple slot machine code, however am struggling to understand classes a little bit. I want to Split this into two classes and not sure how to go about it. My idea is to take the first half which is doing the random generation. Creating a class called Reels, and putting the code in  method like public void spin(). Although, when I split it into another class and tried to call the spin method things got crazy... I apologize if this was not the easiest explanation and hope/appreciate any help I can get.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Arrays;
       
    
    
    public class LabProgram {
    
    
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       
          final int numReels = 3; //Declare how many reels spin on machine
          Random random = new Random(); // Create Random
    
          int[ ] symbols = new int[numReels]; // Create an array of three random numbers
          String[ ] logo = new String[numReels]; // Second Array to assign numbers to symbols
          final String[] allSymbols = {"Cherry", "7", "Grape", "Orange", "Lemon", "Spade", "Club", "Diamond", "Heart", "Ace"}; // A final list of what symbols there are
          
          
          for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; ++i) { // Loop through the integer list to obtain random numbers
             symbols[ i ] = random.nextInt(10); //Random numbers from 0 - 9
          //System.out.println(symbols[i]); Test to make sure list is looping properly
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; ++i) { // Assign second array to the correct symbol according to number
             logo[i] = allSymbols[symbols[i]];
    }
             
          
       //Test each element in list to make sure obtaining correct values
    //System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[0] + " logo: " + logo[0]);
    //System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[1] + " logo: " + logo[1]);
    //System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[2] + " logo: " + logo[2]);
       
       // Simplify each element by assigning to single letter variables
       int a = symbols[0];
       int b = symbols[1];
       int c = symbols[2];
       
       String answer = "Y"; // Variable to be used in while loop (continue playing or not)
       int userBet; // Variable for amount user bets
       int doub; //Variable for reward when user matches two symbols
       int trip; //Variable for reward when user matches three symbols
       int jack; //Variable for reward when user matches three jackpot symbols
       int amountWon = 0;
       
       System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple Slot Machine! Enter a betting amount to spin!!"); // Print intro to user
       
       do { //do-while loop for when answer variable is Y or y
       userBet = scnr.nextInt(); // Take input for betting amount
       if (userBet < 10) { // Bet must be higher than $10
        System.out.println("Bet must be higher then $10");
       }
       
       if (a != b && a != c && b != c) { // When no symbols match the user loses amount that was bet
          System.out.println("You lost your $" + userBet);
          amountWon -= userBet;
       }
       else if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1) { // When all jackpot symbols match user wins Jackpot and adds to winnings
        jack = userBet * 100;
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have won with a " + logo[0] + ", " + logo[1] + ", " + logo[2] + " the jackpot of $" + jack);
        amountWon += jack;
       }
       else if (a == b && b == c) { // When three symbols match user wins triple award and adds to winnings
        trip = userBet * 70;
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won with a Triple!" + logo[0] + ", " + logo[1] + ", " + logo[2] + " $" + trip); 
        amountWon += trip;
       }
       else if (a == b || a == c || b == c) { // When two symbols match user wins award and add to winnings
        doub = userBet * 30;
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won with a Double!" + logo[0] + ", " + logo[1] + ", " + logo[2] + " $" + doub);
        amountWon += doub;
       }
       System.out.println("Continue? Y/N "); // Once awards accounted for ask if player continues or not
       answer = scnr.next();
    } while (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y"));
      if (!answer.equals("Y")) {
         if (amountWon < 0) { //Print statement for when player is in the hold
          System.out.println("You ended losing " + amountWon +" dollars" + ", but people always stop before they hit it big!");   
         }
         else { // Print statement for when player is in positive
        System.out.println("You ended with $" + amountWon + " come back again!"); 
         }
       }
      
       }
          
       }
```

Better visual of how I am splitting code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Reel {
   
   public void spin() {
   final int numReels = 3; //Declare how many reels spin on machine
      Random random = new Random(); // Create Random

      int[ ] symbols = new int[numReels]; // Create an array of three random numbers
      String[ ] logo = new String[numReels]; // Second Array to assign numbers to symbols
      final String[] allSymbols = {"Cherry", "7", "Grape", "Orange", "Lemon", "Spade", "Club", "Diamond", "Heart", "Ace"}; // A final list of what symbols there are
      
      
      for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; ++i) { // Loop through the integer list to obtain random numbers
         symbols[ i ] = random.nextInt(10); //Random numbers from 0 - 9
      //System.out.println(symbols[i]); Test to make sure list is looping properly
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; ++i) { // Assign second array to the correct symbol according to number
         logo[i] = allSymbols[symbols[i]];
}
}
   
}

import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
   


public class LabProgram {


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
   Reel action = new Reel();
         
   action.spin();   
   //Test each element in list to make sure obtaining correct values
//System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[0] + " logo: " + logo[0]);
//System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[1] + " logo: " + logo[1]);
//System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[2] + " logo: " + logo[2]);
   
   // Simplify each element by assigning to single letter variables
   int a = symbols[0];
   int b = symbols[1];
   int c = symbols[2];
   
   String answer = "Y"; // Variable to be used in while loop (continue playing or not)
   int userBet; // Variable for amount user bets
   int doub; //Variable for reward when user matches two symbols
   int trip; //Variable for reward when user matches three symbols
   int jack; //Variable for reward when user matches three jackpot symbols
   int amountWon = 0;
   
   System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple Slot Machine! Enter a betting amount to spin!!"); // Print intro to user
   
   do { //do-while loop for when answer variable is Y or y
   userBet = scnr.nextInt(); // Take input for betting amount
   if (userBet < 10) { // Bet must be higher than $10
    System.out.println("Bet must be higher then $10");
   }
   
   if (a != b && a != c && b != c) { // When no symbols match the user loses amount that was bet
      System.out.println("You lost your $" + userBet);
      amountWon -= userBet;
   }
   else if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1) { // When all jackpot symbols match user wins Jackpot and adds to winnings
    jack = userBet * 100;
    System.out.println("Congratulations! You have won with a " + logo[0] + ", " + logo[1] + ", " + logo[2] + " the jackpot of $" + jack);
    amountWon += jack;
   }
   else if (a == b && b == c) { // When three symbols match user wins triple award and adds to winnings
    trip = userBet * 70;
    System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won with a Triple!" + logo[0] + ", " + logo[1] + ", " + logo[2] + " $" + trip); 
    amountWon += trip;
   }
   else if (a == b || a == c || b == c) { // When two symbols match user wins award and add to winnings
    doub = userBet * 30;
    System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won with a Double!" + logo[0] + ", " + logo[1] + ", " + logo[2] + " $" + doub);
    amountWon += doub;
   }
   System.out.println("Continue? Y/N "); // Once awards accounted for ask if player continues or not
   answer = scnr.next();
} while (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y"));
  if (!answer.equals("Y")) {
     if (amountWon < 0) { //Print statement for when player is in the hold
      System.out.println("You ended losing " + amountWon +" dollars" + ", but people always stop before they hit it big!");   
     }
     else { // Print statement for when player is in positive
    System.out.println("You ended with $" + amountWon + " come back again!"); 
     }
   }
  
   }
      
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view your problem as a user interacting with SlotMachine, and can have a class responsible for user actions while other class for SlotMachine feature and operations.
User will triggerSlot using SlotMachine.
SlotMachine will perform the reels data population.
SlotMachine will also evaluate the amount based on user trigger whether user win or loose.

```
public class SlotMachine {
    
    static int[] symbols = new int[3]; // Create an array of three random numbers
    static String[] logo = new String[3]; // Second Array to assign numbers to symbols
    static final String[] allSymbols = {"Cherry", "7", "Grape", "Orange", "Lemon", "Spade", "Club", "Diamond", "Heart", "Ace"}; // A final list of what symbols there are


    static void triggerSlot() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; ++i) { // Loop through the integer list to obtain random numbers
            symbols[i] = random.nextInt(10); //Random numbers from 0 - 9
            //System.out.println(symbols[i]); Test to make sure list is looping properly
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; ++i) { // Assign second array to the correct symbol according to number
            logo[i] = allSymbols[symbols[i]];
        }
    }

    static int runResult(int userBet, int amountWon) {
        int a = symbols[0];
        int b = symbols[1];
        int c = symbols[2];
        int doub; //Variable for reward when user matches two symbols
        int trip; //Variable for reward when user matches three symbols
        int jack; //Variable for reward when user matches three jackpot symbols

        if (a != b && a != c && b != c) { // When no symbols match the user loses amount that was bet
            System.out.println("You lost your $" + userBet);
            amountWon -= userBet;
        } else if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1) { // When all jackpot symbols match user wins Jackpot and adds to winnings
            jack = userBet * 100;
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You have won with a " + logo[0] + ", " + logo[1] + ", " + logo[2] + " the jackpot of $" + jack);
            amountWon += jack;
        } else if (a == b && b == c) { // When three symbols match user wins triple award and adds to winnings
            trip = userBet * 70;
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won with a Triple!" + logo[0] + ", " + logo[1] + ", " + logo[2] + " $" + trip);
            amountWon += trip;
        } else if (a == b || a == c || b == c) { // When two symbols match user wins award and add to winnings
            doub = userBet * 30;
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won with a Double!" + logo[0] + ", " + logo[1] + ", " + logo[2] + " $" + doub);
            amountWon += doub;
        }
        return amountWon;
    }
}
```

```
public class User {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
//
        //Test each element in list to make sure obtaining correct values
        //System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[0] + " logo: " + logo[0]);
        //System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[1] + " logo: " + logo[1]);
        //System.out.println("symbol #: " + symbols[2] + " logo: " + logo[2]);

        // Simplify each element by assigning to single letter variables


        String answer = "Y"; // Variable to be used in while loop (continue playing or not)
        int userBet; // Variable for amount user bets

        int amountWon = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple Slot Machine! Enter a betting amount to spin!!"); // Print intro to user

        do { //do-while loop for when answer variable is Y or y
            userBet = scnr.nextInt(); // Take input for betting amount
            if (userBet < 10) { // Bet must be higher than $10
                System.out.println("Bet must be higher then $10");
            }else {
              SlotMachine.triggerSlot();
              amountWon = SlotMachine.runResult(userBet, amountWon);
            }
            System.out.println("Continue? Y/N "); // Once awards accounted for ask if player continues or not
            answer = scnr.next();
        } while (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y"));
        if (!answer.equals("Y")) {
            if (amountWon < 0) { //Print statement for when player is in the hold
                System.out.println("You ended losing " + amountWon + " dollars" + ", but people always stop before they hit it big!");
            } else { // Print statement for when player is in positive
                System.out.println("You ended with $" + amountWon + " come back again!");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Also, I observe there is a bug in your approach, you populated the slots data once but while asking user for more bets you are not revising the data. Please check.

Comment: Man this was a lot easier than I was making it out to be! I seriously cannot appreciate your help enough and for spotting the bug. I am going to be using this as a reference for future projects I do, and its fun dissecting all the improvements you did. Thank you again!